# Stop a For Loop and start it at next instance where it stopped

Tags: c#, loops

So this loop is my first attempt at changing many things. I'm not sure I'm going about it the right way. This is for a rught/wrong answer game. Each time they answer wrong, the loop is called.

In my head it would go to the if related to numAttempts. So if numAttempts ==4 you would see "Wrong Answer 2 tries left!" But each time until the fifth attempt, when the loop is called it always starts at the top regardless of the numattempts.

To mitigate this I also tried adding numAttempts++ in the message check (wrong) code block.

I like the idea of the four loop, because based on each wrong answer a different image will appear, based on HangmanImage() --not currently defined--

I've tried break and return between the for if statements but it isn't working. Can you help me when the loop is called to start the loop where numAttempts =. EX. start at numAttempts==2? And stop the loop after the specific instance is completed?

I'm new to coding and trying to make it work. I appreciate your Patience if my work is 100% wrong or that I shouldn't have done a four look. reading a book and the web is great, but every now again, especially in the beginning people need guidance. Please take a moment and push me in the right direction.

Thank you for your time.

```
 int numAttempts = (0); // global variable, at the start of the class. This allows the variable to be used anywhere with the current value


    int maxAttempts = (5);


    static void UpdateImage()
    {
        for (int numAttempts = 0; numAttempts < 6; numAttempts++)
        {
            if (numAttempts == (1))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong Answer 4 tries left!");

                {
                  //  HangmanImage();
                }

            }
            else
                if (numAttempts == (2))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Answer 3 tries left!");

                    {
                //    HangmanImage();
                    }


                }
                else
                    if (numAttempts == (3))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Answer 2 tries left!"); 
                        {
                 //           HangmanImage()
                        }  

                    }
                    else
                        if (numAttempts == (4))
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Answer 1 try left!"); 

                            {
                              //  HangmanImage()
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            if (numAttempts == (5))
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("You Lose!");

                                 {
                               //     HangmanImage();
                                 }
                            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Err, you seem to have missed the point of for loops - do the same thing a few times. All that excess code may make it hard to see real issues. How about `if (numAttempts != 0) { MessageBox.Show("Wrong Answer " + (5-numAttempts) + " tries left!"); }`

Comment: How about using switch? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Also, if numAttempts is global, why do you declare it again in the `for` loop by adding a `int` at the beggining

Comment: @John3136 Thanks! that does what I've been trying to get, and is much less complicated!!! want. With that code would I put my HangmanImage ()? Before your code or after?

Comment: @TheUknown Only because I was told it had to be the same. numAttempt is global and is used during the answer. If the answer is wrong numAttempt goes to 1,2,3 etc. when numAttempt == maxAttempt (5) the game is over. 

Are you saying that I wasn't restricted to numAttempt? if so, would/could it have made the loop better at all? 

Also thanks for the link on switches. Headed over there now.

Comment: @Newbie190 You'd put `HangmanImage()` after the `if` beacuse you want it to run everytime you go through the loop, not just when you print an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working answer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z2BaYs

This is the code. Basically, you use the `for` loop to keep the game in play until the user either runs out of attempts or answers correctly.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var maxAttempts = 5;
        var correctAnswer = "Edam";
        for(int actualAttempts = 1; actualAttempts <= maxAttempts; ++actualAttempts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the only cheese that's made backwards?");
            Console.WriteLine("Attempt #" + actualAttempts);
            var answer = Console.ReadLine();
            if(answer.Equals(correctAnswer))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
                break;
            }
            switch(actualAttempts)
            {
                case 1: 
                    Console.WriteLine("Whoa. Nice try.");
                    break;

                case 2: 
                    Console.WriteLine("Nope. Wrong.");
                    break;

                case 3: 
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect sir!");
                    break;

                case 4: 
                    Console.WriteLine("Still not the correct answer.");
                    break;

                case 5: 
                    Console.WriteLine("...and your done.");
                    break;

                default :
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is some example output/input.

```
What is the only cheese that's made backwards?
Attempt #1
Cheddar
Whoa. Nice try.

What is the only cheese that's made backwards?
Attempt #2
Mozarella
Nope. Wrong.

What is the only cheese that's made backwards?
Attempt #3
Havarti
Incorrect sir!

What is the only cheese that's made backwards?
Attempt #4
Swiss
Still not the correct answer.

What is the only cheese that's made backwards?
Attempt #5
Edam
Correct!
```

Comment: Any chance to get it in one message box?

Comment: That's up to you, @Newbie190.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell that you are doing this for school, so I don't want to give much away. But too your question, you are wanting to keep the same iteration in the loop, if I am understanding you. Just to try and stick to your code, you would need to pass in a variable and return one on the function. Like this

```
    int updateImage(int count)
    {
        for(count < 6; count++)
        {
            Do what you need;
        }

        return count;
    }
```

That way you can pass your iteration in and out of the function. Hope this helps.

Comment: Forgot to say you can use break in there to jump out of loop.